# create and count dynamic object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to compute a result from an array for objects that I can count how many values for each key and add its own `dbId` to the same computed result within the object name!
the reason behind that is to use it to chart.js. so I can check each result  value comes with its own `dbIds`

```js
const obj = [
  {
    dbId: 26598,
    properties: [
      { attributeName: "BIM7AATypeCode" },
      { displayCategory: "Identity Data" },
      { displayName: "BIM7AATypeCode" },
      { displayValue: "221" },
    ],
  },
  {
    dbId: 26591,
    properties: [
      { attributeName: "BIM7AATypeCode" },
      { displayCategory: "Identity Data" },
      { displayName: "BIM7AATypeCode" },
      { displayValue: "221" },
    ],
  },
  {
    dbId: 3695,
    properties: [
      { attributeName: "abc" },
      { displayCategory: "Identity Data" },
      { displayName: "BIM7AATypeCode" },
      { displayValue: "123" },
    ],
  },
  {
    dbId: 3697,
    properties: [
      { attributeName: "abc" },
      { displayCategory: "Identity Data" },
      { displayName: "BIM7AATypeCode" },
      { displayValue: "123" },
    ],
  },
];

// type Histogram = {
//   [key: string]: number;
// };

let histogram = {}; //as Histogram

for (let iterator of obj) {
  for (let { displayName, displayValue } of iterator.properties) {
    //@ts-ignore
    histogram[displayName] = histogram[displayName] | {};

    if (!histogram[displayValue]) {
      histogram[displayValue] = 1;
    } else {
      histogram[displayValue] = histogram[displayValue] + 1;
    }
  }
}

console.log(histogram);

//expected result:

/*

{
  BIM7AATypeCode: {
    "221": 2,
    dbid: [26598, 26591],
  },
  abc: {
    "123": 2,
    dbid: [3695, 3697],
  },
};
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the `Array.reduce` implementation.

Logic

- Loop through `obj` array using `Array.reduce`
- From each object in the array, pick the `properties` key. From this select node having key `attributeName` which is attribute node and with `displayValue` which is display value node.
- Check whether the accumulator has a node with the `attributeName`.
- If not, push a node to accumulator, with the `displayValue` having vale 1 and `dbid` as a single noded array.
- If accumulator already have this node. Update the count of `displayValue` and push the new `dbid`

```js
const obj = [
  { dbId: 26598, properties: [{ attributeName: "BIM7AATypeCode" }, { displayCategory: "Identity Data" }, { displayName: "BIM7AATypeCode" }, { displayValue: "221" }] },
  { dbId: 26591, properties: [{ attributeName: "BIM7AATypeCode" }, { displayCategory: "Identity Data" }, { displayName: "BIM7AATypeCode" }, { displayValue: "221" }] },
  { dbId: 3695, properties: [{ attributeName: "abc" }, { displayCategory: "Identity Data" }, { displayName: "BIM7AATypeCode" }, { displayValue: "123" }] },
  { dbId: 3697, properties: [{ attributeName: "abc" }, { displayCategory: "Identity Data" }, { displayName: "BIM7AATypeCode" }, { displayValue: "123" }] },
];
const output = obj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const attribute = curr.properties.find(node => node.attributeName);
  const displayValue = curr.properties.find(node => node.displayValue);
  if (acc[attribute.attributeName]) {
    acc[attribute.attributeName][displayValue.displayValue] ? acc[attribute.attributeName][displayValue.displayValue]++ : acc[attribute.attributeName][displayValue.displayValue] = 1;
    acc[attribute.attributeName].dbid.push(curr.dbId);
  } else {
    const newAttribute = {
      [displayValue.displayValue]: 1,
      dbid: [curr.dbId]
    }
    acc[attribute.attributeName] = newAttribute;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```